# I wish to remove the header and the footer but retain the page number,

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr

i wish to remove the header and the footer of my acknowledgements page but retain the page number, i'm easily able to do this by using `thispagestyle{plain}` but it ends up placing the page number in the center of the footer, i want it in the right corner, how do i do that?
also editing the code as given in the documentation of the package `fancyhdr`, which is `\thispagestyle{fancy}{
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
}`, works for the acknowledgements page but ends up editing all the other pages too, which is removing their headers too...
my question is, is there no way in which i can edit a single page's header, footer and pagenumber without altering the ones of other pages.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small compilable document that shows your problem called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Just edit your question and add missing code.

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from the documentation of `fancyhdr`:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all header and footer fields
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
```

Comment: it doesn't help, because the `fancyhf{}` removes my header and footer

Comment: ...@RBK, you said "I wish to remove the header and footer". So yes, it removes your header and footer.

Comment: More exactly: After Bernard's code, `\thispagestyle{plain}` removes the header and footer, and the page number will be in the right corner of the footer.

Comment: @RBK: It *first* removes header and footer. But the second action is to add a footer in the right corner. So globally, it replaces the previous page style.

Comment: @Rmano, yes i did say that, but only for that particular page, but the code ends up removing header and footer from all the pages, i just don't want it on that particular page

Comment: @RBK That's not clear at all; please edit the question. Nevertheless, using the above definition and `\thispagestyle{plain}` should work just for the page in question. Please do a bit more research, edit your question and post an MWE. We can surely help then.